# How can I code a table with "individually controlled cells" like in the example picture using HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've been looking online and haven't found anything that can help with making a table like this one.
[image]
already tried using `colspan`, but it didn't work as I'd hoped.

anyone's got any other ideas?

EDIT:
*tried this*

```css
table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: auto;
        }
        th { /* text */
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
        }
        td { /* pictures */
          padding: 5px;
          text-align: left;
        }
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td>Month</td>
                    <td colspan="2">Savings</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">January</td>
                    <td>$100</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td colspan="2">$50</td>
                  </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: please share what you tried.

Comment: @DanielA.White will do, but as I said, my main issue is that I haven't found anything other than `colspan` to try

Comment: great that you tried it but why not share your example as a starting point and then we can discuss solutions -rather than answer "how do i do this"

Comment: @DanielA.White my bad there, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "table-layout: fixed" to your css as shown below:

```
table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: auto;
        table-layout: fixed;
        }
        th { /* text */
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
        }
        td { /* pictures */
          padding: 5px;
          text-align: left;
        }
```

to get
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS grid:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.box div:nth-child(4n + 1),
.box div:nth-child(4n + 4) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.box div {
  outline: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Month</div>
  <div>Savings</div>
  <div>January</div>
  <div>$100</div>
  <div>February</div>
  <div>$50</div>
</div>
```